# Appeal to Pity? 'don't give me a ticket. My parents will take the car away from me and my life will be miserable.'

Tags: fallacies

<sub>Source: p 214, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (2000 6 ed) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel)</sub>

> Fallacy: Appeal to Pity
>   Definition/Hints: Seeking to persuade not by presenting evidence 
>   but by arousing pity
>   **[1.]** Example/Method: "Please, officer, don't give me a ticket. My 
>   parents will take the car away from me and my 
>   life will be miserable."

If the Conclusion is:

2. I am not guilty of a ticket.

Then 2 is an AtP because criminal guilt is an independent conclusion and question from emotional misery due to the ticket.

3. Don't give me a ticket.

Then how is 1  an Appeal to Pity (abbreviated to AtP)? Is not 1 a Valid Syllogism as follows? 3 differs from the Protasis of 4, and so 4 and 5 would not apply.

4. If an officer gives me a ticket, then my parents will take the car away from me.
5. If my parents will take the car away from me, then my life will be miserable.

Comment: If you consider 4 and 5 as the premises of an [Hypothetical syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_syllogism), then the conclusion will be: "If an officer gives me a ticket, then my life will be miserable." So what ?

Comment: @ChrisSunami Thanks. I did remember my other question when I wrote this question above, but I questioned again because I still cannot distinguish myself the good and bad examples of this fallacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion is not "I am not guilty". That would be nonsense.

And it's not an appeal to pity. It is a claim that the punishment would in this particular case be much harsher than for many other people. If I get a £50 ticket, it costs me £50. If this person gets a £50 ticket, they claim that it costs them £50, plus loss of use of the car.

So that person is trying to convince the police officer that in his particular case the ticket together with its consequences would be an unacceptable harsh punishment, and therefore letting the guilty person get away with it.

Not dishing out an overly harsh punishment is not "pity". Whether the argument is convincing is another matter.